# Create Firefox bookmark with dynamically updating date in URL

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

I have a website that includes today's date in the link:

http://www.example.com/2016/08/29/

How can I create a Firefox bookmark that, when followed, replaces the date portion with the then-current date? In other words, when I open it tomorrow it should take me to:

http://www.example.com/2016/08/30/

Comment: What's wrong with dragging the URL to the bookmark toolbar?

Comment: @DavidPostill This will result in a fixed bookmark for `http://www.example.com/2016/08/29/`. But it won't be `http://www.example.com/2016/08/30/` tomorrow.

Comment: Then you should clarify your question ...

Comment: @DavidPostill I tried. Is it clearer now?

Comment: [so] duplicate [Bookmark with date in the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7509010)

Comment: [How to create a dynamic bookmark with today’s date in the URL](http://trendblog.net/how-to-create-a-dynamic-bookmark-with-todays-date-in-the-url/)

Comment: @DavidPostill Thanks for the links! I will have a look at them and report back.

Comment: @DavidPostill The second website you linked did the job. Thank you very much. Do you want to answer? Otherwise I can post a self-answer.

Comment: Feel free to self-answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Big thanks to [@DavidPostill](https://superuser.com/questions/1118822/bookmark-including-current-date?noredirect=1#comment1597257_1118822) for linking to the following blog that covers the problem:

http://trendblog.net/how-to-create-a-dynamic-bookmark-with-todays-date-in-the-url/

I was able to modify the example there to get the desired result:

```
javascript:function url(){

    var date = new Date();

    var y = date.getFullYear();
    var m = date.getMonth()+1;
    var d = date.getDate();

    if(m < 10){m = '0' + m;}
    if(d < 10){d = '0' + d;}

    var date = y + "/" + m + "/" + d;

    return 'http://www.example.com/'+ date +'/';

} window.open(url(),"_parent");
```

Some points that can be adjusted:

- `_parent` : opens the link in the current window
- `_blank` : opens it in a new window
- `_self` : replaces the current one with a new window

To use the bookmark: add a new bookmark, edit it and copy&paste the above code in the URL field. Don't be alarmed if all the spaces are converted to `%20`, it works nevertheless.